# use of triple scalar product to prove an equality

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

$a,b,c$ are unit vectors mutually inclined at an angle $\theta$.
Given that $$(a\times b) + (b\times c)=pa+qb+rc$$  where $p,q,r$ are constants and $a,b,c$ represent the above mentioned vectors. Prove that
$$r^2 + p^2 + \frac{q^2}{\cos\theta}=2.$$

Comment: I edit your post. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you, actually I am new here so i dont know much on how to operate

Comment: Read this if you want to learn. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Let $\, \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}+\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} =
  p\mathbf{a}+q\mathbf{b}+r\mathbf{c}$

$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ gives

> $$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} =
>   p+(q+r)\cos \theta  \tag{1}$$

$\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ gives

> $$0 = q+(r+p)\cos \theta  \tag{2}$$

$\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ gives

> $$ \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} =
>   r+(p+q)\cos \theta \tag{3}$$

$(1)-(3)$,
$$0=p(1-\cos \theta)+r(\cos \theta-1)$$

For $\cos \theta \ne 1$,
$$p=r \tag{4}$$

Substitute $(4)$ in $(2)$,

$$q=-2p\cos \theta \tag{5}$$

$\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ gives

> $$
> (\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})^2+(\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})^2+2
>   \begin{vmatrix}
>     \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{b} \\
>     \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} & \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}
>   \end{vmatrix} =
>   p^2+q^2+r^2+2(pq+qr+rp)\cos \theta $$

\begin{align*}
  2\sin^2 \theta+2(\cos^2 \theta-\cos \theta) &=
  (p^2+r^2)+q^2+2rp\cos \theta+2q(r+p)\cos \theta \\
  2(1-\cos \theta) &=
  2p^2+4p^2\cos^2 \theta+2p^2\cos \theta-8p^2\cos^2 \theta \\
  &= 2p^2(1+\cos \theta-2\cos^2 \theta) \\
  &= 2p^2(1-\cos \theta)(1+2\cos \theta) \\
  p^2 &= \frac{1}{1+2\cos \theta} \\
  p^2+r^2+\frac{q^2}{\cos \theta} &=
  \frac{2}{1+2\cos \theta}+\frac{\cos \theta}{1+2\cos \theta} \\
  &= 2
\end{align*}
provided $\, -\dfrac{1}{2} < \cos \theta <1$